# vector iterator not behaving properly

Tags: pointers, vector, error-handling, syntax

I want to iteratively use `insert` to modify the first element in a `vector<int>`(I know that with vector it's better to insert element in the back, I was just playing).

```cpp
    int main() {
        vector<int> v1 = {1,2,2,2,2};
        auto itr = v1.begin();
        print_vector(v1);
        cout<<*itr<<endl; // ok, itr is pointing to first element
        v1.insert(itr,3); 
        cout<<*itr<<endl; // after inserting 3 itr is still pointing to 1
        print_vector(v1); 
        cout<<*itr<<endl; // but now itr is pointing to 3 
        v1.insert(itr,7); 
        print_vector(v1); 
        cout<<*itr<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

> v[]: 1 2 2 2 2  
> 1 
> 1 
> v[]: 3 1 2 2 2 2  
> 3 
> v[]: 131072 3 1 2 2 2 2
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

So my problem here are mainly 2:

1. After `v1.insert(itr,3)`, `itr` is still pointing to `1`. After the call of `print_vector()` now `itr` is pointing to `3`. **Why**?
2. Ok now `itr` its pointing to `3` (the first element of `v1`). I call `v1.insert(itr,7)` but instead of placing 7 as the first element, it place `131072`. Again, **why**?

The `print_vector` function I have implemented is the following:

```cpp
void print_vector(vector<int> v){
    cout<<"v[]: ";
    for(int i:v){
        cout<<i<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After inserting an element to a `vector`, all of its iterators are invalidated, meaning any behavior involving them falls under undefined behavior. You can find a list of iterator invalidation conditions in the answers on [Iterator invalidation rules for C++ containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules-for-c-containers).

Anything you're experiencing after the first `v1.insert()` call falls under undefined behavior, as you can clearly see with the placement of `131072` (an arbitrary value).

If you refresh the iterator after every insertion call, you should get normal behavior:

```cpp
int main()
{
    vector<int> v1 = { 1,2,2,2,2 };
    auto itr = v1.begin();
    print_vector(v1);
    cout << *itr << endl;

    v1.insert(itr, 3);
    itr = v1.begin(); // Iterator refreshed

    cout << *itr << endl;
    print_vector(v1);
    cout << *itr << endl;

    v1.insert(itr, 7);
    itr = v1.begin(); // Iterator refreshed

    print_vector(v1);
    cout << *itr << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
v[]: 1 2 2 2 2
1
3
v[]: 3 1 2 2 2 2
3
v[]: 7 3 1 2 2 2 2
7
```